# Javascript copy array of properties to another object (one-liner)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is obviously straight-forward using traditional loops, but I'm curious if anyone can think of a nice, compact way of doing it with destructuring and the spread operator.

For example, let's say I have

```
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const list = ['a', 'd'];
```

I'd like to create `bar = { a: 1, d: 4 }`.

You could do something like

```
const bar = {};
list.forEach((p) => { bar.p = list.p; });
```

But I'm wondering if anyone has a slick one-liner using ES2015+. For example, you can do `const { b, c, ...bar } = foo`, but that's if you have the inverse known prior to runtime.

While the solution ideally would support a dynamic list of properties in an array, one with a statically known list is better than nothing. (For example, `const bar = ({{ a, d }} = foo)`

Comment: i mean... you could use reduce on list, but... it's not any more of a 1liner than forEach is.

Comment: `const bar = list.reduce((o, p) => (o[p] = foo[p], o), {});`

Comment: This depends -- it looks like you're making a clone of the object. If a shallow copy works, you can use `const bar = Object.assign({}, list);` (sort of, depends on your loop) to make a copy by reference

Comment: `let bar = (x => {list.map( k => x[k]=foo[k] );return x;})({});`

Comment: @KevinB Any reason you reopened it? If there was an ES6 way to do it purely with destructuring, it would be on that question.

Comment: It's certainly similar, but it isn't a dupe of either.

Comment: @KevinB I don't see any point in keeping this as a unique question. It's got all the same solutions we've all seen before.

Comment: Me either. doesn't mean it should be incorrectly closed.

Comment: @KevinB I disagree that it's an incorrect closure. This question has no unique value.

Comment: `let bar = (x=>list.reduce((a,b)=>{return a[b]=foo[b],a},{}))({});`

Comment: @KevinB It does indeed seem like a dup. The only difference I can see is that the OP is providing the list of properties to "pick" as an array of strings, but that's probably not essential to what he is trying to do. And the fact that he mentions destructuring would seem to indicate that he is open to that kind of solution, which is what the proposed dup provides. What is your thinking about why it's not a dup?

Comment: I agree that it's the same fundamental problem. I didn't find the old one when searching (very little keyword overlap). Hopefully the cross-listing will help. @torazaburo thanks for the elegant answer.

Comment: @terry87 Please unaccept my answer so I can delete it, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The best I think you'll be able to do is with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const list = ['a', 'd'];

const bar = list.reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = foo[k], o), {})

console.log(bar)
```

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain why?

Comment: Probably a this-should-be-marked-as-dup-not-answered downvote, which some people do sometimes, and of which I am sometimes guilty myself.